# Trigger change on dynamic and dependent select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select options independent `cats` and dependent `subcats`. by showing a detail row of table I want to get the selected values from the current row of table.
Its selecting the `cat` option but not selecting `subcat` which is dependent on `cat`.
I am using ajax in my real code to show a table row detail and get select options data.

**UPDATE**

NOW its working in the demo by replacing `category` in `option value='" +value.category+` by `value.subcategory` suggested by @msg . But the problem still exists and its still not working in my real code as i am using ajax and getting the select options data and triggering change in ajax success function.
Example with ajax in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr3o5unj/5/).

This is the demo

```js
var data = [
{"id":1,"category":"Mechanism","subcategory":"Allergic reaction"},
{"id":2,"category":"Mechanism","subcategory":"Bloodborne"},
{"id":3,"category":"Mechanism","subcategory":"Bugbite"},
{"id":4,"category":"Mechanism","subcategory":"Chemical"},
{"id":5,"category":"Mechanism","subcategory":"Electrical"},
{"id":6,"category":"Object","subcategory":"Sara lift"},
{"id":7,"category":"Object","subcategory":"Shower"},
{"id":8,"category":"Object","subcategory":"Table"},
{"id":9,"category":"Object","subcategory":"Wheelchair"}
];

$("#incimechtype").change(function(){
    var dropdown = $(this).val();
   $("#incimech").find("option").remove();
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
      if(value.category == dropdown)
       $('#incimech').append("<option value='" +value.subcategory+ "'  data-subcat='" +value.id+ "'>" +value.subcategory+ "</option>");
});
        changeOptions();
});

function changeOptions() {
  var selectedOption = $('#incimech').find('option:selected');
  $('#ids').val(selectedOption[0].dataset.subcat);
}

$(".show").click(function(){
 $(hide).show();
  var cat = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cats').text();
  var subcat = $(this).closest('tr').find('.subcats').text();
  $("#incimechtype").val(cat).trigger('change');
  $("#incimech").val(subcat);
});
```

```css
#hide {
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="cats">Mechanism</td>
    <td class="subcats">Chemical</td>
    <td><button class="show"> show detail </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cats">Object</td>
    <td class="subcats">Table</td>
    <td><button class="show"> show detail </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="hide">
<label for="incimechtype">Mechanism Type</label>
<select name="incimechtype" id="incimechtype">
   <option value="Mechanism">Mechanism</option>
   <option value="Object">Object</option>
</select> 
<br>
<br>
<label for="incimech">Mechanism</label>
<select id="incimech" onChange="changeOptions()">
</select> 
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="ids">
</div>
```

Comment: Your subcategory options have all the same `value`: `option value='" +value.category+` I guess you want `value.subcategory`

Comment: @msg thank you its working in jsfiddle now, But actually in my real code i am using `ajax` to get the value of `subcategory` that's why its still not working at my end.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to select the element before is fully loaded? Sorry, I can't help without knowing what's going on or seeing the code.

Comment: @msg you can see the ajax function i have used in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvLx0cr6/). i am getting the selected option in the success function.

Comment: That response has a different structure than the array. Even if that's correct, you trigger `change` before selecting the value, that empties the select. Is the new value in the old dataset?

Comment: @msg the main problem is to `.trigger('change')`. I have tried this `$('#incimechtype').trigger('change');` placing before ajax function. which is also not working.

Comment: @msg And the response structure is not the issue, I have just minimized it in the jsfiddle to make it readable. Because I have a bunch of code in my real structure if i share it, It will be time consuming to read and understand it.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question, what code is from your "real" code and what is faked here?  In your JSFiddle what is `mid`, and where does it come from?  I tried simulating mid as one of the ids in your `data` array, but then I get errors about `dataset` referenced in `changeOptions()` but which does not exist.  Also your code shows `data-subcat`, but that is not used anywhere ... Please try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), nobody can help if we can't even understand the question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have assigned mid to each table row. you can see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr3o5unj/5/). I want the jsfiddle work as it is working in this code snippet tool here. And the difference is ajax , I am using ajax in success function i want to trigger change on category and get selected subcategory value.

Comment: [Here is a cleaned up, simplified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/81a02jdm/).  AFAICT it works fine - is that what you are after?  I made changes, and described them in comments, but I still don't really understand the problem.  If I am on the right track, pls let me know, and I will add an answer and clarify.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes i want the exact result as in your fiddle. And its really needs clarification because its still not working at my end and giving error  `data is not defined` on this line `response = data[id];`

Comment: That line is just simulating your AJAX response - you would not use it in your "real" code.  Why are you using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with something closer to your real code, it is possible to understand your problem.

The problem was occurring because the Mechanism select was being populated via a 2nd AJAX call, fired from the success callback of the first AJAX call.  But because AJAX is *asynchronous*, it does not complete immediately, but will not hold up execution.  Whatever code comes after the AJAX call will run before the AJAX has finished.

To explain in pseudo-code, the `.show` AJAX success callback looked like:

```
success: function(response) {
    // 1. Set selected mechanism type
    // 2. AJAX call to populate mechanism dropdown
    // 3. Set selected mechanism option - Whoops!  2 has not
    // finished yet!  3 runs before 2 has finished!  Whatever 
    // changes you do to the mechanism options here will be
    // overwritten and lost when 2 updates them!
}
```

To avoid this, you have to move anything that must run *after* the mechanism options have been repopulated in the success callback for *that* AJAX call.

```
// .show AJAX
success: function(response) {
    // 1. Set selected mechanism type
    // 2. AJAX call to populate mechanism dropdown
}

// mechanism populate AJAX
success: function(response) {
    // 1. populate mechanism dropdown
    // 2. set selected mechanism
    // 3. copy selected id to input field.
}
```

[Updated, working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/Lfsz8cbt/).

Note that since you've provided several iterations of code, and I've updated each in turn, there are a lot of changes from your original code. They are all described in the JSFiddle.

Comment: I am still facing the problem. Its fetching the correct data to the `subcategory` options list but not selecting  the correct one like `Chemical`. Maybe I am trying to select the element before the trigger change is fully loaded.  I have tried this `$('#incimechtype').trigger('change');`  placing before ajax function. which is also not working.

Comment: I don't think I can help more without seeing your *real* code, and a sample of what the AJAX response looks like.  As I suggested earlier, please try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My code looks similar to the jsfiddle i provided.And my AJAX response is also giving correct output in developer tool network tab. And when I try to show the subcategory in a text box instead of select element its also giving correct output. I think the main issue is the correct place where to trigger change. in the same success function its not fully loaded when i trying to select it. And showing the first `subcategory` as selected from the list.

Comment: @Eniol Is the `data` array in your JSFiddle really in your code, or is that just there to show what your AJAX response looks like?  I have updated my JSFiddle, and it works, but I am still not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry i was forgot to add the ajax function while getting `subcategory` list in the jsfiddle. I have added ajax function to it now its result is same as i am facing in my real server. As you can see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a19p5jb/) now. could you make this jsfiddle work now.

Comment: Oh man ... you really make it hard to help!! :-| But finally it is possible to understand the problem, and the solution.  I have updated my answer.